# Azure Function with two output bindings (Azure Queue & Blob Storage)

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-http-trigger

Is it possible to write an azure http trigger function with two output bindings, so that data not only outputs to an azure queue but also sends the same message to an azure blob storage?

Comment: yes, that's working. You can add many outbound bindings

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Comment: Can you please provide me with any links that explain it?

Answer (score 1):

Please find a sample for multiple outbound bindings here:

```cs
    public async Task<IActionResult> Sample(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "sample")] HttpRequest req,
[Queue("sample", Connection = "StorageAccountString")] CloudQueue sampleQueue,
[Blob("sample", FileAccess.Read, Connection = "StorageAccountString")] CloudBlobContainer sampleContainer,
ExecutionContext context,
ILogger log)
    {
        var requestBody = await req.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        var queueMessage = new CloudQueueMessage(requestBody);
        await sampleQueue.AddMessageAsync(queueMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);

        CloudBlockBlob blob = sampleContainer.GetBlockBlobReference($"{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}");
        blob.UploadText(requestBody);

        return new OkResult();
    }
```

Here you can find multiple Blob outbound bindings:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#example

```cs
**using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.PixelFormats;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing;

public class ResizeImages
{
    [FunctionName("ResizeImage")]
    public static void Run([BlobTrigger("sample-images/{name}")] Stream image,
        [Blob("sample-images-sm/{name}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream imageSmall,
        [Blob("sample-images-md/{name}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream imageMedium)
    {
        IImageFormat format;

        using (Image<Rgba32> input = Image.Load<Rgba32>(image, out format))
        {
            ResizeImage(input, imageSmall, ImageSize.Small, format);
        }

        image.Position = 0;
        using (Image<Rgba32> input = Image.Load<Rgba32>(image, out format))
        {
            ResizeImage(input, imageMedium, ImageSize.Medium, format);
        }
    }

    public static void ResizeImage(Image<Rgba32> input, Stream output, ImageSize size, IImageFormat format)
    {
        var dimensions = imageDimensionsTable[size];

        input.Mutate(x => x.Resize(dimensions.Item1, dimensions.Item2));
        input.Save(output, format);
    }

    public enum ImageSize { ExtraSmall, Small, Medium }

    private static Dictionary<ImageSize, (int, int)> imageDimensionsTable = new Dictionary<ImageSize, (int, int)>() {
        { ImageSize.ExtraSmall, (320, 200) },
        { ImageSize.Small,      (640, 400) },
        { ImageSize.Medium,     (800, 600) }
    };

}**
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your function app in an isolated process, Microsoft has a brief discussion and example here:

[Isolated process - Multiple output bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#multiple-output-bindings)